# Automatically defining permission on sub folder which is automatically created

Tags: workflow, permissions, folder

I have my sharepoint integrated with microsoft dynamics CRM, when any account is created in CRM it creates same named folder in sharepoint within "Account" list. when any order is created for that account in CRM, it creates sub-folder of order within that account. so hierarchy goes like below.

Accounts > Sample Account > Salesorder > Order 1
Accounts > Sample Account > Salesorder > Order 2

Account list is inheriting permission from site, I want to keep that intact, but when any subfolder named "Salesorder" is created, I want to define permission where specific users can see only. Salesorder folder is created by CRM for each account order is created.

Can we have anything useful in sharepoint I can make use of ? may be workflow?

Sorry If i have used wrong terms I am newbie in sharepoint.

Regards.

Comment: You'll need to break inheritance and set unique permissions when the folder is created.

Answer (score 2):

If its a SharePoint On premise.. i suggest you go for an Event Receiver to break permissions. If its SharePoint 2013 you can use a SP 2013 workflow to break permission as well.